# SQL Messages Output appearing as Errors in SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis, business-intelligence, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

So my SSIS Package logs messages from the query execution as errors whenever query execution fails. So for instance my query has 2 Print statements and for some reason query fails because of some error. SSIS is logging all the 2 print statements along with the actual error. I don't want SSIS package to log print messages as Errors. My package is reading this information on "OnError" event handler. and the source of the logs is set to : System::ErrorDescription. Consider the following query:

```
PRINT 'Trying to set string value to a datetime column.'
PRINT 'So i should get this error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'
UPDATE TempTable SET CreateDateTime = 'StringValue'
```

Below is the output/Message from SQL Management Studio. Last line being the actual error, and remaining lines are all Print Statements.

```
Trying to set string value to a datetime column.
So i should get this error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

**Msg 3930, Level 16, State 1, Procedure pr_TempTable, Line 3 Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.**
```

But all these three lines from messages window is treated as multiple errors by OnError event handler in SSIS when i try to execute SQL task and run this query.

Comment: Yes, more information please.

Comment: That's more data but we need information. What does the stored procedure look like? What generates the exception? What does your error handling look like? You've tagged this as ssis-2012 and ssis-2008 which one is it? If 2012, are you using package or project deployment model?

Comment: What do you mean it's "output from SQL Management Studio".   What makes you think it's logging the print statements as an error, which is something entirely different?

Comment: @TabAlleman - By output i meant the information you see in the Message window in SSMS after you run a query or a procedure.

Comment: @billinkc - I honestly don't think it has anything to do with the version of SSIS, nor with using a package or project deployment model, or with what kind of exception the stored proc is getting. I will update the question with a sample query. It has to do with the behavior of "OnError" eventhandler in SSIS and PRINT statements used in a query.

Comment: So again I ask, what makes you think it's logging the print statements as an error?    And I would add to that, why do you care what you see in the message window in SSMS?

Comment: @TabAlleman - When i run the SSIS package locally, in the progress window i see all the print messages returned by query, along with the actual error, are captured as errors. So taking the example above, during package execution, in Progress window i see three errors are captured (2 of them really are print statements and 1 is actual error encountered by query). I don't care when i see in SSMS, but i am sending errors encountered by SSIS in email to a group. And i dont want to send just the error not the print statements.

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the code that you are using to send the email?

Comment: @TabAlleman - Package logs all the errors in database and then in a separate task, package reads them and send email for each of them. I off course can create a script task to send only one email when there are collection of errors. But i am very much interested in knowing the root cause as why "onError" event handler will capture Print Messages as error, whenever the query fails.

Comment: I am curious too, which is why I am trying to get you to show the code that causes the behavior.   Can you post the code that logs the errors in the database?

Comment: Although it doesn't explain why, this shows somebody finding the same issue.   Apparently it is standard behavior, and you will apparently have to work around it:   http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1354462-391-1.aspx

Comment: @TabAlleman - Thanks for sharing that link. I also came to the same conclusion that it is the standard behavior and i'll have to work around it. Thanks for looking into this. Much appreciated. You can post the same as answer, so i can close the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, I suspected that you were actually "Print"-ing your statements with RAISERROR, which is a fairly common practice.

However, on further research, I found that it seems to be standard behavior for PRINT commands to be included in the error message that is sent to a calling application by a subsequent RAISERROR in the same script.

So if you don't use RAISERROR in your script, your PRINT statements will not be treated as errors by SSIS.   But if you do use RAISERROR, any PRINT statements that occurred before the RAISERROR will be included in the error message that gets raised.

It's weird and far from intuitive, but it seems to be the standard behavior and it looks like you'll just have to work around it.